# @Valid annotation not working in simple project

Tags: java, maven, validation, console

Here's my simple Java demonstration code:

```
package com.demo;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       @Valid @NotNull Object x = null;
       System.out.println("Shouldn't print this!");
    }
}
```

And this is my Maven configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>untitled1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

The output is:

```
Shouldn't print this!
```

The expected behaviour is throwing an exception with the validation error.

Why does this simple code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Annotations by itself do nothing. Every annotation requires some sort of processor to handle the Annotations (you can consider annotations as hints). Here you need a validation processor to make it work. Have a look at https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation

Answer (score 0):

What you have as dependency is bean validation api, you could use an implementation like `hibernate-validator`  which transitively pulls validation api.

In a Java SE environment you would need an EL implementation as well.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
   <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
   <version></version>
</dependency>
```

Usually you would use to validate the attributes of an entity type class, just as an example the below class has an attribute that must not be null.

```
public class ValidationExample {
    
        @NotNull
        private Object name;
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
            Validator validator = factory.getValidator();
            Set<ConstraintViolation<ValidationExample>> violations = validator.validate(new ValidationExample());
    
            for (ConstraintViolation<ValidationExample> violation : violations) {
                System.out.println(violation.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

Should give:

```
INFO: HV000001: Hibernate Validator 6.1.6.Final
must not be null
```

More here : [Hibernate validator](http://hibernate.org/validator/documentation/getting-started/)